# How to plot one set of data as solid line for one domain and as dashed line for another domain?

Tags: plotting, data

Consider a set of data {{x,y}}. How to plot it in the way such that for all x > x0 the plot line will be solid, while for x < x0 it will be dashed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = SortBy[RandomReal[10, {50, 2}], First];
x0 = 3;
ListLinePlot[data,  
 Mesh -> {{x0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Dashed, Dashing[{}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does this work with ListLogPlot?

Comment: @JohnTaylor, it does if you add the option `Joined->True`. Try `ListLogPlot[data,  Joined -> True, Mesh -> {{x0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Dashed, Dashing[{}]}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0]]`

Comment: Thank you again! Sorry again, but could you please tell how to plot two datasets data1, data2 and apply the meshing only to one of them?

Comment: @JohnTaylor, you can plot the two datasets separately  and combine them using `Show`.